# Does {lang:x} work?

Tags: multi-language, multilingual, language

The EllisLab documentation on search results includes an interesting code snippet:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th>{lang:title}</th>
        <th>{lang:excerpt}</th>
        <th>{lang:author}</th>
        <th>{lang:date}</th>
        <th>{lang:total_comments}</th>
        <th>{lang:recent_comments}</th>
    </tr>
 (...)
```

Source: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html

I'm trying to find documentation on how to use `{lang:...}` and where the values come from. Taking recent_comments as an example, I'm not finding it in any of the lang files. My attempt to take one from the English core_lang.php (`system_off_msg`) didn't work either.

Any thoughts? Was this just a placeholder in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These special variables are only used in the Member module and Search module on the front-end - they won't be parsed anywhere else. Why, I do not know.

To see what they correspond with, take a look at this snippet from the Search module code:

```
// Parse lang variables
        $swap = array(
            'lang:total_search_results' =>  lang('search_total_results'),
            'lang:search_engine'        =>  lang('search_engine'),
            'lang:search_results'       =>  lang('search_results'),
            'lang:search'               =>  lang('search'),
            'lang:title'                =>  lang('search_title'),
            'lang:channel'              =>  lang('search_channel'),
            'lang:excerpt'              =>  lang('search_excerpt'),
            'lang:author'               =>  lang('search_author'),
            'lang:date'                 =>  lang('search_date'),
            'lang:total_comments'       =>  lang('search_total_comments'),
            'lang:recent_comments'      =>  lang('search_recent_comment_date'),
            'lang:keywords'             =>  lang('search_keywords')
        );
```